# Language of a ketubah for marriage

Tags: marriage, language, aramaic, legal-documents, ketubah

Can I write a ketubah in English or possibly in Hebrew?  Or must it be in Aramaic?  The problem is that my friends and I do not speak Aramaic any longer.  Our Babylonian-Jewish ancestors did, but we no longer have the *minhag* to speak Aramaic as our native language, nor do we even understand what most of it even means.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Do you need to understand it that readily? I have to hire specialized lawyers to handle most legal documents that I sign.

Comment: Note that this is hardly a new issue nowadays; in Geonic times and later, few people spoke Aramaic either (which is why the later Geonim and early Rishonim wrote a lot of their works in Arabic).

Comment: Well, I was at a wedding last week, and when the Mesader Kiddushin finished reading the Ketubah, he asked the Chattan if he understood everything, and he said yes immediately even without thinking about it.  So it made me wonder if the question of *mitzvot tzrichin kavana, o lo* applies here.

Comment: i've usually seen ketubot written in Aramaic and $LOCAL_LANGUAGE.  So ketubot with either Aramaic + Hebrew or Aramaic + English or in one case, Aramaic + Klingon.

Comment: @DoubleAA I disagree - You should understand the terms to which you agree on a contract. Lawyers will explain pieces or technical phrases, but would you sign a contract written in Farsi or Urdu without a certified translation?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman I trust the mesader kiddushin to tell me exactly what I'm agreeing to (ie. a certifying party). I think most people do.

Comment: I just found something that can answer your question [(Emes LeYaakov, Avos 1:1)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47585&st=&pgnum=325): Aramaic is used as a remembrance that we are still in galus.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question which surprisingly doesn't return a clear answer via a Google search, so submitted this question to the wonderful Talmidei Chachamim of the [Kollel Iyun HaDaf](https://www.dafyomi.co.il/).

To which they replied:

[image]

Ie while by the strict letter of the law you technically "may" be able to write a ketubah in a non-Aramaic language... **this is definitely not something which is advisable**.

(R' [**Binyamin Adler**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binyomin_Adler)'s  "[Nisuin K'Hilchasam](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/43206/%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%9D-%D7%91-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D---%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9C%D7%A8)" ⬅️ sefer.org.il link)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!